# How to use filter in sqlalchemy with three parameter

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a code like this:

```
price = Price.query.filter(and_(Price.product_id == data['product_id'], Price.min_qty >= data['quantity'], Price.max_qty <= data['quantity'])).first()
```

It doesn't work and gives error, but if I only use 2 parameters, it is good

```
price = Price.query.filter(and_(Price.product_id == data['product_id'], Price.min_qty >= data['quantity'])).first()
```

Why can't I have three parameters? I search everywhere and didn't find the answer. I try to achieve SELECT * FROM price WHERE product_id = 'product_id' AND min_qty = 'quantity' AND max_qty = 'quantity'

Thank you

Comment: give us the error you get?

Comment: @senaps it doesn't give error but when I call price.price didn't show anything

Comment: I think my logic thats make error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
query = Price.query.filter(Price.product_id == data['product_id'])
query = query.filter(Price.min_qty >= data['quantity'])
price = query.filter(Price.max_qty <= data['quantity']).first()
```

Or use the and to use one line less.

Comment: thank you, the problem is my logic is error, I found your code interesting to filter than one line